# LEFT OUTER JOIN, filtered by date

Tags: mysql, left-join, outer-join

I want to query this:
select the contracts that are:
- active,
- with start_date BEFORE now,
- with end_date AFTER now,
AND,
- that have NO matched record from rents.

Note that `Rent.month` is a date data-type column, with "yyyy-mm-dd" content format.
If this condition is removed, i get the correct records.

Using this query i get an empty result-set

```
SELECT `Contract`.*
FROM `contracts` AS `Contract`
LEFT JOIN `rents` AS `Rent` ON ( `Rent`.`contract_id` = `Contract`.`id` )
WHERE 
Contract`.`active` = 1
AND `Contract`.`end_date` > NOW( )
AND `Contract`.`start_date` < NOW( )
AND DATE_FORMAT( `Rent`.`month` , '%Y-%m' ) <> DATE_FORMAT( NOW( ) , '%Y-%m' )
AND `Rent`.`id` IS NULL
```

What am i doing wrong?

### edit

I also tried 
`AND DATE_FORMAT(`Rent`.`month`, '%Y-%m' ) = DATE_FORMAT( NOW( ) , '%Y-%m' )`
same empty set

Comment: you want this part 'AND DATE_FORMAT( `Rent`.`month` , '%Y-%m' ) <> DATE_FORMAT( NOW( ) , '%Y-%m' )' in the join predicate not the where?

Comment: The test on `Rent.month` in the `WHERE` clause eliminates all records where `Rent.month` is null, implicitly turning your outer join into an inner one.  You must perform that test within the join condition (or else add `OR Rent.month IS NULL` to the `WHERE` clause, using parentheses to apply the correct precedence).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This condition filters all not null match of rent

```
AND DATE_FORMAT( `Rent`.`month` , '%Y-%m' ) <> DATE_FORMAT( NOW( ) , '%Y-%m' )
```

While this condition filters all null match of rent

```
AND `Rent`.`id` IS NULL
```

The first condition doesn't seem to meet any of your initial requirements and basically this:
- that have NO matched record from rents.

I will try to remove first condition from where clause.

edited after comment:
A way that I prefer to write condition of no match is using the exists operator in this manner:

```
SELECT `Contract`.*
FROM `contracts` AS `Contract`
WHERE 
Contract`.`active` = 1
AND `Contract`.`end_date` > NOW( )
AND `Contract`.`start_date` < NOW( )
AND NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT * FROM `rents` AS `Rent` 
  WHERE
  `Rent`.`contract_id` = `Contract`.`id` 
  AND DATE_FORMAT( `Rent`.`month` , '%Y-%m' ) <> DATE_FORMAT( NOW( ) , '%Y-%m' )
)
```

This way is more readable and maintainable to me.

Comment: I need this criteria, so i've changed it to `=` instead of `<>`. empty again

Comment: Sorry yossi probably I didn't understand the meaning of this sentence "that have NO matched record from rents". Maybe the correct solution is to add the criteria in the join predicate as suggested from Mike and eggyal. But the sentence should be: